# VS Code Live Server vs Firebase Hosting -- In the context of href/src Firebase does not like '/' characters, and VSCode needs them. What gives?

Tags: html, firebase, visual-studio-code, liveserver

For example,

If I want to use Live Server to check out changes to my personal site,

```
  <link rel="icon" type="icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

will be deployed just fine to Firebase. However, if I want to use Live Server, I'll have to change the markup as such to something like

```
 <link rel="icon" type="icon" href="/site/public/assets/img/favicon.ico">
```

This is clearly a some Firebase / json issue, but and am wondering if anyone else has encountered this? If so, how did you fix it?

Comment: The path for Live Server on VSC depends on the path where you open the project (which is the root). Meanwhile, for firebase, the root is always the folder where you set as "public" in firebase.json.

Comment: Gotcha, I just don't seem to get why even those my assets are in the public folder. Deploying them with / in the relative path does not work.